# Why (or when) is the direct limit of compact spaces paracompact?

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

I'm working through Milnor and Stasheff's *Characteristic Classes* and got stuck in chapter 5, p.66, where some (supposedly) easy facts about paracompact spaces are assembled. One of these is:

> **Theorem of Morita.** If a regular topological space is the countable union
> of compact subsets, then it is paracompact.

What I can't seem to wrap my head around is the following corollary:

> **Corollary.** The direct limit of a sequence $K_1 \subset K_2 \subset K_3 \subset \ldots $ of compact
> spaces is paracompact. ...
>
> For it follows from [Whitehead, 1961, §18.4]
> that such a direct limit is regular. (The reader should have no
> difficulty in supplying a proof.)

The referenced paper is

- J.H.C. Whitehead, *Manifolds with transverse fields in Euclidean space*, Annals of Math. 73 (1961), pp.154-212, [JSTOR link](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1970286).

I get how $\varinjlim_{i}K_i = \bigcup\limits_{i}K_i$ but I have no clue how to prove regularity when the $K_i$ aren't even assumed to be Hausdorff. The reference takes the $K_i$ to be normal Hausdorff spaces, so I don't see how that helps.

Comment: What does Whitehead say?

Comment: He states (without proof) that the space $X=\varinjlim_i A_i$ where $A_i \subset A_{i+1}$ closed and normal Hausdorff is itself a normal  Hausdorff space. Other approaches I have seen make use of the fact that $X$ is a $k_{\omega}$-space but surely that can't be the elementary proof that Milnor alludes to...

Comment: Are you sure that Milnor isn’t taking *compact* to mean *compact Hausdorff*?

Comment: @Brian Well, this is embarassing. You're absolutely right, actually a footnote in chapter 10 reads: "The proof goes through perfectly well for non-Hausdorff spaces provided that one substitutes 'quasi-compact' (i. e., every open covering contains a finite covering) for 'compact' throughout." I wasn't aware that this distinction is made outside of algebraic geometry. For the sake of completeness: A proof that the direct limit of nested compact Hausdorff spaces is normal can be found on page 4 in: http://www.topology.auburn.edu/tp/reprints/v02/tp02105.pdf